# Geometry Nodes: Point Instance Collection use count (object weighting)

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to recreate the donut sprinkles tutorial (by Blender Guru) but instead of using a particle system for sprinkles on the top of a donut, I want to use the new geometry nodes system.

When using a particle system you can use a collection as the objects and then the "Use Count" option allows you give different objects in the collection different count.  This means you can make certain objects in a collection appear more often than other objects.

When using a Point Instance Geometry node you can choose "collection" but there is no option to "Use Count".  Is there some chain of nodes you could use to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: See this https://devtalk.blender.org/t/geometry-nodes/16108/1308 and this https://devtalk.blender.org/t/geometry-nodes/16108/1309 for a discussion about it, while waiting for the official implementation

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I found was to add separate "point distribute" and "point instance" nodes for the spheres and then you can independently control the density of the spheres and sprinkles. You then join the geometries.[image: node diagram]

The two nodes controlling the spheres are circled in red.

Comment: This only works if you have very few objects to deal with. With a large quantity however, this wont be a good solution. For this specific task, It's best to stick with the particle system at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I asked myself the same. I found a workaround that gives a bit more control. I splitted the point instance in two - one with the object which is more important and another with a collection of variation. With the Attribute Randomize I can give more importance to one of the separated instances:
[image: screenshot of nodes]

Answer (score 2):

I cobbled together a quick and simple method for my project.

Set two value nodes that correspond with the amount of items in your collection, starting at 0. In this example there are 5 items total. Run them through a mix RGB node, then control the factor with a noise texture + colour ramp.

If you tweak the colour ramp a bunch it could be a quick and dirty way to choose which items in the collection have the most importance. Hope that's useful to someone!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at this this:
https://blenderartists.org/t/geometry-nodes-creating-a-random-object-picker-with-rarity/1337111

This is the best for current state for fields

More clean result for 4 indecies look like:
[image]

So random value group is just Random value node
[image]